# Swipetabs for activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have made a swipe tabs using fragments. But is possible to use activities instead of fragments? For example. I have 3 swipetabs, "View","Add","Delete" and 3 seperate activities for each on of these functions. Is there a way that if a swap from "View" to "Add", it takes me to the "Add" activity, an so on.

Comment: Why do you want to use Activity instead of Fragments?

Comment: Communication is more easier in activities than fragments

Answer (score 0):

As i don't have enough reputation i cannot comment on this so am answering. Instead of using activity try to use fragment as google suggests you can do everything in fragments same as you can do in activity infact you can do more thing in fragments so i recommend you to use fragments so please take a look at communication between two fragments https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: You have to make a separate communicator for transferring data in case of fragments if I am not wrong. In case of activities, you just need to use "extras". I have to add a whole lot of communicators which is a tedious thing to do. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @ashay please take a look at documentation it has described everything infact it is best practice to use fragments instead of using activity it will boost up the performance

Comment: even use can pass bundle in fragments by using setarguments and for retrieving getarguments